# Get Starting and ending of a Dataset in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to extract the starting and ending points of a data set from a table. For Ex if data is like:

```
1
5
10
15
20

40
45
50
55
60
65
70
```

Now the 2 data sets are 1 - 20 and 40 - 70. So the Data will always be sequential and the difference between points in a single dataset will max be 7. So the resultant query should give me 3 columns:

```
1. 5  15
2. 45 65
```

i.e second and second last point in the dataset.

Is it possible to do without using a cursor of forloop. Please post a query if you can.
I tried doing is using `over` and `partition by` but no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you properly, this returns what you're asking for.

```
DECLARE @tmp TABLE
    (
        numVal INT PRIMARY KEY
    );

INSERT @tmp
VALUES
    ( 1 )
    ,( 5 )
    ,( 10 )
    ,( 15 )
    ,( 20 )
    ,( 40 )
    ,( 45 )
    ,( 50 )
    ,( 55 )
    ,( 60 )
    ,( 65 )
    ,( 70 );

;WITH breaks AS
    (
        SELECT 
            t.numval breakMax
            , ROW_NUMBER()
                OVER(
                    ORDER BY t.numval
                    ) breakGroup
        FROM 
            @tmp t
        WHERE 
            NOT EXISTS
                (
                    SELECT
                        NULL
                    FROM 
                        @tmp t1
                    WHERE
                        t1.numVal > t.numVal
                        AND 
                        t1.numVal <= t.numVal + 7
                )
    )
SELECT
    v.breakGroup
    , MIN(v.numval) secondNum
    , MAX(v.numVal) secondLastNum
FROM 
    ( 
        SELECT
            t.numVal
            , br.breakGroup
            , ROW_NUMBER()
                OVER(
                    PARTITION BY 
                        br.breakGroup
                    ORDER BY 
                        t.numval 
                    ) ar
            , ROW_NUMBER()
                OVER(
                    PARTITION BY 
                        br.breakGroup
                    ORDER BY 
                        t.numval DESC
                    ) dr
        FROM    
            @tmp t
        CROSS APPLY
            (
                SELECT 
                    TOP 1
                    breakGroup
                FROM 
                    breaks b
                WHERE    
                    b.breakMax >= t.numVal
                ORDER BY 
                    b.breakGroup 
            ) br
    ) v
WHERE
    v.ar = 2
    OR 
    v.dr = 2
GROUP BY 
    v.breakGroup
```

Comment: Added more to my question. Thanks for Answering, Great Help

Comment: Dont Worry about it, was making a silly mistake. All Good Buddy. thanks a ton.